# Python script to compare two CSV files with same rows for new lines/differences

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a python script with `nmap` to run monthly to check open ports.this is how the csv file looks like:

```
host    hostname    hostname_type   protocol    port    name    state    product    extrainfo   reason  version conf    cpe
82.214.228.176  176.228.214.82.in-addr.arpa PTR tcp 21  ftp open            syn-ack     3   
82.214.228.176  176.228.214.82.in-addr.arpa PTR tcp 22  ssh open            syn-ack     3
```

Then when I run it again and will add another line if new port is open:

```
82.214.228.178  hnsmonitor.direcpceu.com    PTR tcp 443 https   open            syn-ack     3
```

So can you help me with an example script to compare the old `old.csv` with the `new.csv` and print to csv file the new lines that are added?

Comment: What is your delimiter here?

Comment: Hi zipa , it is ";".That is how the ouput looks like from the script:

Comment: host;hostname;hostname_type;protocol;port;name;state;product;extrainfo;reason;version;conf;cpe
82.214.228.176;176.228.214.82.in-addr.arpa;PTR;tcp;21;ftp;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.176;176.228.214.82.in-addr.arpa;PTR;tcp;22;ssh;open;;;syn-ack;;3;

Comment: But in your question you posted the output with spaces and not semicolons. Please make sure the format in the question is correct.

Comment: Hi Byte, you are right sorry.It is my first question here so next time will try to be more specific.The first output was from the csv file itself.Later i posted the ouptut from the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using `pandas` this will do it:

```
import pandas as pd

old = pd.read_csv('old.csv', sep=';')
new = pd.read_csv('new.csv', sep=';')
final = new[~new.isin(old)].dropna()
final.to_csv('diff.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: Hey Zipa, i was exactly looking at pandas based on suggestions around.let me give it a try and get back to you and apreciate your propmt answer

Comment: i think we are going teh right direction but this is the ouptut from the script:   /Scan# cat diff.csv 
;host;hostname;hostname_type;protocol;port;name;state;product;extrainfo;reason;version;conf;cpe .The only difference b/n the files is this line on the new csv:    82.214.228.70;dsl-radius-01.direcpceu.com;PTR;tcp;631;ipp;open;;;syn-ack;;3;   ..So wondering why got the first line as diff..

Comment: If you are referring to header line it is because the code is designed to keep header. To remove it from output you can use `final.to_csv('diff.csv', sep=';', header=False)`

Comment: tnx Zipa, gave it try but i got an enpty diff.csv file somehow the script is not catching the extra lines on the new file.Any ideas?..let me know if you need some output

Comment: I figured it out..:) .Thanks

Comment: actully is still not working as expected.Will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

old csv entries = list_a

new csv entries = list_b

These lists will have unique identifiers from the data in csv.

List item

Code to remove list_a items from list_b to get the new added entries:

```
for item in list_a:
    while list_b.count(item) > 0:
        list_b.remove(item)
```

Comment: tnx nbirla but how to print out to a new csv file..i am missing sometimng here..sorry but i am new to python..:)